# Multiplicity conflicts with the referential constraint

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm receiving the following EF error:

> Agent_MailingAddress: : Multiplicity conflicts with the referential
>   constraint in Role 'Agent_MailingAddress_Target' in relationship
>   'Agent_MailingAddress'. Because all of the properties in the Dependent
>   Role are non-nullable, multiplicity of the Principal Role must be
>   1

It *appears* to throw this when it executes
 `base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder).`

Here are my models. FWIW, `Agent` inherits from a `User` class.

```
public class Agent
{
    public int AgentId { get; set; }
    public int PrimaryAddressId { get; set; }
    public Address PrimaryAddress { get; set; }
    public int? MailingAddressId { get; set; }
    public Address MailingAddress { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
}
```

I believe the issue has something to do with the fact that `Agent` has more than one property of type `Address` and possibly also because one of them is nullable.  I've done some searching, but can't seem to find an answer.

I assume altering my `Agent` model to have a single property of type `List<Address>` that would use a `UserAddresses` lookup table would resolve the error, but I would prefer to keep the current model and not.

How can I resolve this error?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code you posted looks ok. The problem must be how you are using it. Show code where the error occurs, and post the full exception message.

Comment: Sorry guys.  Updated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problems creating a Foreign-Key relationship on Entity Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17420064/problems-creating-a-foreign-key-relationship-on-entity-framework)

Comment: Do you have any configuration in `OnModelCreating`?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

This can happen if your configuration and your model do not match.

Let's say in your db configuration you have a rule like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Agent>().HasRequired(x=>x.MailingAddress);
    //..
```

But in your model you say that MailingAddress is optional:

```
public int? MailingAddressId { get; set; }
```

> I believe the issue has something to do with the fact that Agent has
>   more than one property of type Address and possibly also because one
>   of them is nullable

It's not the case.

Comment: I feel like an idiot.  The AgentConfiguration had `Property(p => p.MailingAddressId).IsRequired();`

Comment: Use in Mapping this.HasRequired(o => o.Address)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(o => o.AddressId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

Answer (score 10):

For database first: if you altered an existing table already added to Entity Framework, say added a foreign key constraint after the fact, delete the table in the EDMX designer and add again and this will resolve the error.

Comment: Exactly my situation, and exactly the solutio which worked.  You don't even have to save your changes in between deleting and adding the table.  I'd changed some fields to NOT NULL and added some relationships, which is I suspect what confused EF.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to determine the root of the problem is the following :

1. open the .edmx file and find the entity containing the foreign key field.
2. find the property that is causing the error message and right click to open the context menu.
3. click properties on the context Menu to open the properties window.
4. Examine the Nullable property for the field and change it to the appropriate value.